# jQuery's best way to check if required filds are filled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a huge form, as part of an ERP with plenty of huge forms with many fields each one.

I am trying now to think about the better way to create a jQuery ckecker about if `.required` fields are empty, preventing then for the event and showing an error message. Submit button will only run when all those `.required` fields are filled.

I do know how to solve this, is not difficult in deed, but I feel this ways are great for simple forms, registration forms, etc... bot not for a system with more than 700 fields. One of the ways I know is setting each value of each field on a `var fieldName = $(#fieldID').val();` and then something like:

```
if (fieldName == "") {
  $("label#name_error").show();
  $("input#name").focus();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

This is greatly correct but I was wondering if you know some way of optimizing this process in order to avoid generating thousands of unnecesary code lines.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `required` attribute or class required, select by this class

Comment: there are various way to do it. You can use jquery validator. And since its ERP I suppose the field info is stored in DB and form is generated dynamically. So you can generate the validator dynamically using the field info. I have made something similar where field info is stored in DB along with the validator info and while generating the form generate the validator using the info from db. You can check here www.sqcrm.com

Comment: recommend http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @Abhik you are right about what you are saying. I will need to take your prupose of checking your code calmly as I guess the whole CRM you link is quite complex. If I need any additional info, I'll tell you ok? Thank you.

Comment: @Nileh, I was trying to solve this with no aditional plugins, at least not as first option. If I find myself unable to make this I'll check that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it on focusout

```
$(':input[required=""],:input[required]').bind('focusout', function(){
     if ($(this).val() == ""){
         $(this).focus();
         //and show some error in whatever way you want 
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, I'll learn how .bind method works and I'll try to follow your recomendation. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, one question, is this method valid to avoid writing separately each checking field? I meand do I have to write it for each one?

Comment: Yes, it works for all input fields, which have required attribute.

Comment: Hi, I am quite close to get this done with your propose, it is beng very useful. I have now the problem that jQuery does not recognise required inputs, and when focusing out, it does not call the function. HTML inputs do have 'require' set. I think this has s.thing to do with ':input[required=""],:input[required]'... do you know why could jQ not be calling the function?

Comment: I have also tried setting inputs to required="true" and seleting $(':input[required="true"]'), and no effect

Comment: 'require' was a mistake or you've written 'require' ? Cause if it's so, you should change it to 'required'. If you've written 'required' and it's still does not work show me some fiddle, cause in my it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/hYdp7/

Comment: SOLVED! You made my day. In any case, I had to delete the : before input when selecting. Now it works as **$("input[required='true']").bind('focusout', function()...** what was the purpose of the :?

Comment: 'require' was a mistake.

Comment: :input selects all form controls. Actually : lets you to check textarea either, so if you have it, it works on it too.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery Validation Plugin. it has several utility methods and and you can also customize it.
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I was trying to solve this with no aditional plugins, at least not as first option. If I find myself unable to make this I'll check that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this plugin for your front end validation:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I was trying to solve this with no aditional plugins, at least not as first option. If I find myself unable to make this I'll check that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($.trim(fieldname) == '' || $.trim(fieldname) == null || $.trim(fieldname) != 'undefined') {
 }
```

or you can use regular expression like

```
  if( '/^(.)*$/'.test(fieldname) ) { }
```

Comment: Hi Sam. The fact is that I would need to make one of this for each field, isn't it?

Comment: if there are many fields then you can use validation plugin as mentioned above. or you can use $.each jquery to check all the fields

Answer (score 0):

for each input field use

`<input name="name1" required />` ( add required attribute )

Answer (score 0):

1: Add jquery validator js file in src script file -   `

2: Code :
inside  tag
 //Validation using Microsoft js validator

```
   $('#myform').validate({
      rules:{
      firstname:"required",
      lastname:"required",
      username:"required" ,
      employeeid:"required",
      email:{
      required:true,
      email:true
      },
      password:{
      required:true,
      minlength:5
      },
      phoneno:{
      minlength:9,
      maxlength:10,

      }
      },
      messages:{
      username:"Please enter your username..!",
      password:"Please enter your password..!"
      },

      submitHandler: function(form) {
      // do whatever you want


      }
      });
```

HTML Form declaration

```
<form  id="myform">
 <input id="username" name="username" type="text"></input>
 <input id="password" name="password" type="password"></input>
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email"></input>
 <input id="phoneno" name="phoneno" type="number"></input>      
 </form>
```

this is one kind of doing validation using jquery validator

Comment: Hi, I was trying to solve this with no aditional plugins, at least not as first option. If I find myself unable to make this I'll check that. Thank you.